# Unable to build signed apk after upgrading to react native 0.59.3

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, react-native-maps

have upgraded recently to react native v0.59.3
and am using react-native-google-places and react-native maps packages latest versions.

when i  try react-native run-android i get compileDebugResources renderscript error for which i made some modifications at buid.gradle of the node modules of the dependency to fix the issue.

Now i am unable to generate a signed apk as i get the error

## Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1'

for which i have to remove node modules and install again thus resulting in the

## compileDebugRenderscript error.

Any suggestions or solutions?

the following are the changes i made to build.gradle of googleplaces and google maps in node_modules

Change in node modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  def googlePlayServicesVersion = safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION)
  // Variable lookup order : googlePlayServicesMapsVersion > googlePlayServicesVersion > DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_MAPS_VERSION
  def googlePlayServicesMapsVersion = safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesMapsVersion', safeExtGet('googlePlayServicesVersion', DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_MAPS_VERSION))
  def androidMapsUtilsVersion = safeExtGet('androidMapsUtilsVersion', DEFAULT_ANDROID_MAPS_UTILS_VERSION)

  compileOnly "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
  implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$googlePlayServicesMapsVersion"
  implementation "com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:$androidMapsUtilsVersion"

  implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
}


In google places node modules build.gradle 
Add 
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"

And 
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
}
```